# I am getting a ValueError for the line 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Getting value error on code line 4.

```
n = int(input("enter number of students: "))
list1=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    ele=int(input("enter the score of the student: "))
    list1.append(ele)
list1.sort()
print("the runner up is: ", list1[-2])
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your program but It actually works fine, could you please paste your `error` that you had. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the entire error message, with traceback.

Comment: what was your input? prolly not a number (or is a float)

Comment: What number are you actually entering? As an example, while `int(float("4.0"))` would work, `int("4.0")` directly does not.

Answer (score 0):

It might have happened because you have accidently provided a character value that cannot be converted to `int`. So in line 4 you are getting `ValueError`. Another possible reason is you have used a decimal point number as input. A decimal number of `str` type cannot be converted to `int` type. So either use a `float` or use `try and except` to handle the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a validation for your code and so try this:

```py
n = int(input("enter number of students: "))
list1=[]
counter = 0
while counter != n:
    try:
        ele=int(input("enter the score of the student: "))
        list1.append(ele)
        counter += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Your input should be a number!")
    
list1.sort()

try:
    print("the runner up is: ", list1[-2])
except:
    print("You should at least have two scores!")
```